# testing REST with shoulda and factory_girl - destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, shoulda, factory-bot

i'm developing test for REST using shoulda and factory_girl. Code below

```
 context "on :delete to :destroy" do
    setup do
      @controller = NewsArticlesController.new
      @request = ActionController::TestRequest.new
      @response = ActionController::TestResponse.new

      @news_article =  Factory.create(:news_article)

    end

    should "destroy new NewsArticle" do
      assert_difference('NewsArticle.count', -1) do
        delete :destroy, :id => @news_article.id
      end
    end

    should_redirect_to news_articles_path
  end
```

as a result i see

```
  1) Error:
test: on :delete to :destroy should redirect to index. (NewsArticlesControllerTest):
ArgumentError: block not supplied
    c:/develop/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thoughtbot-shoulda-2.10.2/lib/shoulda/action_controller/macros.rb:201:in `instance_eval'
    c:/develop/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thoughtbot-shoulda-2.10.2/lib/shoulda/action_controller/macros.rb:201:in `__bind_1248853182_16800
0'
    c:/develop/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thoughtbot-shoulda-2.10.2/lib/shoulda/context.rb:351:in `call'
    c:/develop/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thoughtbot-shoulda-2.10.2/lib/shoulda/context.rb:351:in `test: on :delete to :destroy should redirect to index. '
```

Could you tell me plz - whats wrong and how i can modify test to make them work right?

UPD: routes looks fine

```
news_articles GET    /news(.:format)                    {:controller=>"news_articles", :action=>"index"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should use a symbol and post method when calling delete:

```
 assert_difference 'Article.count', -1 do
    post :delete, :id => ...
  end
```

(referenced from http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Testing/Assertions.html#M001427)

Comment: No, assert_difference works fine, but as you can see in provided logs - there are problem with should_redirect_to news_articles_path

Comment: I think, you don't get redirected to the index after deleting? or do you?

Comment: def destroy
    @news_article = NewsArticle.find(params[:id])
    @news_article.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(news_articles_url) }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    end
  end

Comment: I dont know if this is the right syntax, but shouldnt "should_redirect_to news_articles_path" be in the should-"destroy new NewsArticle"-block?

Comment: I mean, does it work if you copy the should_redirect_to news_articles_path under the assert_difference statement?

Comment: huh .... working :) but i've changed should_redirect_to to assert_redirected_to news_articles_path

Answer (score 5):

The problem is with `should_redirect_to` which now uses block to evaluate the redirect code. Sadly, neither thoughtbot wiki, nor the readme at github reflect this and still contain the old examples.

The correct code is

```
should_redirect_to "news articles page" { news_articles_path }
```

where the first argument is just a textual description (it is not eval'd as with the older version) used to generate a test name, so you get a test name like *'should redirect to news articles page'*

Answer (score 1):

tkramar solution points in the right direction, but i've had to write the code as:

```
should_redirect_to("news articles page") { news_articles_path }
```

Also see the new manual at http://dev.thoughtbot.com/shoulda/classes/Shoulda/ActionController/Macros.html#M000015